# Can we add Code Review to the migration list?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, code-review-se

You often times see a question asking for someone to review their code. Could we add Code Review to the list?

Comment: Probably worth reminding folks here that [Code Review is not a debugging service](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/about) - questions from folks asking for a "review" because their code *doesn't work and they're too lazy to explain how* are not good migration candidates. The code should at least *work* before it is put up for review - if your team does code reviews, you probably have the same rule internally. (I see a lot of misguided flagging from folks who don't quite get this)

Comment: let's reopen this up!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the last 90 days, there's been 64 questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review, with only 6% rejected by Code Review. That's:

- An appreciable number of questions
- A rather good success rate

The problem is, Code Review is still in beta, and we're *very* much against establishing migration paths to beta sites, we need to be absolutely sure that they're going to graduate before we facilitate a conduit for content to go to them.

However, I'll go out on a limb and say that we'll *very likely* set this up once Code Review is set to graduate, possibly even before the design and such are ready. Of all the migration paths on the network, this is definitely one of the more obviously good ones.

Until then, the Stack Overflow moderators can continue to send questions over as needed. As far as migrations go, these are pretty cut and dry as Code Review's scope is very clear.

Comment: Why is it still in beta?

Comment: @ColeJohnson It can't quite yet sustain its first election, but is well on the way there.

Comment: looking at [CR stats at Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review) made me wonder, why they are _still_ beta? However, upon checking respective [discussion at their meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/556/5799) and their [reputation stats](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all), it seems to make sense. **Zero** 20Kers and **only 3** 10Kers, oh my. CR users indeed need to **[vote more](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/612/5799)**

Comment: @gnat That's pretty much it, the site has to be able to sustain an election and be able to handle the rep/privilege scale sliding. I have no doubt it will get there.

Comment: @gnat: Bingo.  Although my response is late, CR is still having this problem.  Some of the Area 51 stats could be a problem.  Today marks Day 1001 of beta status.

Comment: @Jamal The only thing holding CR back from graduating is the lack of high rep users - there just aren't enough 1k+, 3k+ users on the site, and it can't quite yet sustain an election. Every single thing about CR is ready but that - it's really just a matter of time at this point (and, well, voting).

Comment: @TimPost: Good to know.  Thanks!  Assuming the voting thing won't improve sufficiently at some point, I hope CR isn't prone to being shut down.

Comment: @Jamal We'd never dream of closing such an active and otherwise healthy site. Once it can sustain an election and we're confident that community moderation won't be _too_ adversely affected by shifting to the 'graduated' privileges scale, I'm sure it'll go. Kind of perplexed as to why voting is so light there, though, but that's just me chewing on it - nothing more :)

Comment: @TimPost: Glad to hear that.  I've been reading some old answers (promarily by Jeff) regarding this on CR's meta, so I was getting nervous.  Anyway, my guess is that there isn't enough experienced users (myself included) knowing when and when not to vote.  On the other hand, it should be easy to vote on questions (up or down).  I hope this isn't calling for... moar badges. :-)

Comment: @TimPost: I have a feeling that CR is by its very nature much more "write-only" than SO: It's essentially unsearchable, and the posts are very specific and of limited use to a general audience. On top of that it's hard work to write a good review for the often rather long pieces of code. So I'm not surprised the voting there doesn't have the same kind of "depth" as on SO...

Comment: Can we get some updated statistics here?

Comment: codereview is not beta anymore, but I still cannot flag posts for migration when reviewing. because there is no such option..

Comment: Almost 5 years later, still not on the migration list...