# Why are we still unable to flag off-topic -> Code Review?

Tags: discussion, migration, code-review-se

Logically speaking, it would seem to me that SO and CR go hand in hand. So everytime I come across a question that would be a better fit for CR, I find it odd that I can't flag the question to migrate to CR.

Before asking this question, I did my research here on Meta and found a few posts regarding this:

['Try Code Review' flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272108/try-code-review-flag) 
[Can we add Code Review to the migration list?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291955/can-we-add-code-review-to-the-migration-list)

Those questions date back to 2014 and the answer clearly states (quote):

> However, I'll go out on a limb and say that we'll very likely set this
>   up once Code Review is set to graduate, possibly even before the
>   design and such are ready. Of all the migration paths on the network,
>   this is definitely one of the more obviously good ones.

It just couldn't happen for as long as CR was still in beta. Right now, CR has graduated for quite some time (2015). Yet still we can't flag for a migration. Is there a specific reason for this? Or did it simply slip through our mods fingers?

Edit: I don't agree with the duplicate question. Although the question is related, it doesn't answer this question. Which is why we're unable to flag for CR despite previous answers to questions telling us it was *most likely* to happen.

The supposed duplicate tells us why we need to be carefull with migrating questions to CR. At best, one can *assume* this was the reason why the option wasn't added. At worst, one can *assume* that when it comes to migration, SO's community can't be trusted. Which in turn could raise some serious questions about Stack Exchange's statement *"We believe moderation starts with the community itself"*

I'm not trying to stir up an unnessesary discussion here or prove some sort of point. All I'm saying is that the question isn't directly answered. One can only make assumptions.

I mean: If it wasn't for the accepted answer to this question, the answer could be that SO wanted to do it, but CR stopped it from happening because they wouldn't be able to handle to load (just an example). Or some technical issue that made it impossible to add another migration to the list and other SE sites took priority.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)? How about [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)? What do you think the chances are that a significant number of people using such a flag will have seen and understood both?

Comment: @Shog9 Yes I've seen both of them. But I didn't know that the choice not to do it was because "most SO members don't fully understand which questions should be migrated or not". The Meta didn't provide me with a clear answer. In fact, just the opposite. That's why I asked :)

Comment: Related: [What is the latest on adding Code Review to Off-Topic Migration Options?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311348/1014587)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With an approximate rejection rate of ~20% with *only* diamond moderators able to migrate questions, the idea of establishing a firm migration path is still a bit trepidatious at this point. Most people don't realize that questions *must* have working code in order to be on-topic there; this isn't something easily explained in the UI itself, which is why we're generally reluctant to introduce new paths to begin with.

Given the volume of questions that would *likely* be erroneously sent over to CR from SO every day, we'd definitely *not* be doing any favors for the people asking these questions *or* the users of Code Review.

Remember, migrations are there to assist in the user's experience, not for bucketing content. If a question can be moved and *very likely* answered promptly on the destination site, it makes great sense to move it. But with caveats that most folks aren't aware of that are a bit outside of our general sense of what makes a good question, it's probably not in anyone's best interests to have the path established at this point.

Otherwise, we'd just be sending over semi-edited walls of code, I'm afraid - and probably at a volume that would *really* annoy Code Review along with the folks asking the precious few in the pile that could have been salvaged.

Comment: The volume wouldn't just annoy Code Review, it would be bigger than the amount of questions we currently get. As a large part of those questions already is off-topic, the amount of moderation involved would get out of hand fast. Already we get too many invalid redirects from SO users pointing here. People don't realize just how small Code Review is compared to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9):

Believe me when I say that [**they know about this**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1687/what-questions-are-suitable-for-migration-to-code-review-and-how-does-the-proce/1688#1688).  Believe me when I say that we would readily send over every question which *looked* like it was more geared towards code review as opposed to genuine, on-topic questions which would be a good fit over there.

**This is not a matter of us setting anything up.** This is entirely on their community being willing to accept what we send over.  Right now, they're not, and given how much crap we get over *here* on a regular basis, I have no confidence that we'll be able to trust the community at large enough to filter through the noise to get valuable signal over to them.